# Perforce, how to merge a file changes between latest revision and the base version from one stream to another?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I have two streams namely S1(let it be a source stream) and S2(target stream). Assuming there is a file "abc.txt" which is currently at version #5. I need to merge the changes that were done in "abc.txt" between #1 and #5 to my target stream S2. Can someone please suggest if this would be possible in perforce?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

```
p4 switch S2
p4 merge --from S1 abc.txt
```

If you want to just merge all outstanding changes from all files, leave off the `abc.txt`.  If you want to just merge a particular range of changes, add the range to the file path (e.g. `abc.txt#4,#5` or `abc.txt@123,456`).